# Mysterious throttling on Linux Centos

Tags: throttling

I have inherited a Linux CentOS install running as a PPPOE server router for guest bandwidth to pass through for a unit block.

Internet connectivity looks like this :-

[DSLAM1]==10.20.20.0/24===.1[CENTOS].1==10.10.10.0/24==.254[FIREWALL]=30Mbit=[INET]

The link was only recently upgraded to 30Mbit and was previously 8Mbit. I have checked the INET_FIREWALL appliance and there is no shaping on there so all signs point to CentOS.

The current behavior I'd like to change is as follows

Downloads from LINUX-CENTOS max out at 1Mbit (128kb/sec) <- I cant find anything that would be limiting this.
Bandwidth coming from the DSLAM maxes out at 4-5Mbit which I also beleive is being controlled on CENTOS.

I have read and read all about 'tc' and how it is used, however from what I can see I dont believe it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you've looked into tc, then you're probably right, still, best to indicate the contents of running:

```
tc qdisc show
tc filter show dev eth0
```

(Adjust with your appropriate device, pp0 or whatever)

Also, take a look at iptables with:

```
iptables -nvL
iptables -t nat -nvL
```

If you don't find any tc or iptables rules responsible, then it could just be a problem with the driver or hardware.